# how to scroll scrollbar horizontally which is inside a window using java

Tags: java, selenium

My problem is to scroll the scroll bar horizontally which is inside window
I used this code but it scroll the windows horizontal bar not that exactly scroll bar inside that window.

```
    WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gvLocationHorizontalRail']"));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(250,0)", "");
```

Answer (score 15):

You are using javascript that scrolls the main window, if you want to scroll a element, you should first get the element by id, then change the its `scrollLeft` property:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
js.executeScript(
    "document.getElementById('gvLocationHorizontalRail').scrollLeft += 250", "");
```

If you instead want to change the scrollbar that moves up and down, you should change the `scrollTop` property.

Comment: @Ferrbig "gvLocationHorizontalRail" which id should we put here? the element that we want to scroll into the view? or the entire window id?

Comment: @qtpseleniumSupport The element that has the scrollbar

Answer (score 6):

```
In addition to answer by Ferrybig, can you try this:

WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gvLocationHorizontalRail']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
js.executeScript(
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", scroll);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the following:

```
WebElement problematicElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='blah']"));
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", problematicElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Javascript to do this. I was having issues with solutions working the second, third and fourth times the page was loaded. The code below works and works always without error. It moves a scroll bar to the right. I broke it out because I prefer to see each action by itself for readability.

```
            myElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".ngscroll-scrollbar")));
            myElement.click();
            Actions move = new Actions(driver);
            move.moveToElement(myElement).clickAndHold();
            move.moveByOffset(125,0);
            move.release();
            move.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could not find the horizontal element of a table, so another (bearish, but still) way to perform this action is:

```
        IWebElement yourElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("id_XYZ"));
        yourElement.Click();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 20)
        {
            yourElement.SendKeys(Keys.Right);
            ++i;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to perform scrolling of elements which are inside a window.
For eg: Webtable

```
WebElement scroll=driver.findElement(By.css(".xyz"));

JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver

js.executeScript("document.querySelector(scroll).scrollLeft=1000");
```

Note: You have to make sure that you have to pass CSS only in the query Selector method