# How to perform windows scroll horizontally in a web application with multiple scroll elements?

Tags: java, selenium, scroll, selenium-chromedriver

**Usecase:** Perform horizontal scroll till the element is found

**Pre-reqs:** Selenium - Java 3.141/chrome

Below are my few sample snippets

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; //create jse object and with this object, execute js

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft += 250",driver.findElement(By.className("wux-scroller")));
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(500,0)"); 
jse.executeScript("scroll(500, 0)");
jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(500,0)"); 
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",el); 
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[1];",driver.findElement(By.className("wux-scroller")), j)
```

**Expected Result:** To perform horizontal windows scroll till the element is displayed

**Actual Result:** Scroll doesn't happen but no exceptions are thrown as well

Note:

- Page has both horizontal and verticall scrollbar
- Both scroll elements has same class  `<div class="wux-scroller wux-ui-is-rendered" >`
- (I think) Windows default scrollers are used for both vertical and horizontal
  scrolls. Image attached. [image]
- If I **replace** **scrollLeft** to **scrollTop** in above snippet then scroll happens vertically
  fine

Referred below link but didn't help

[how to scroll scrollbar horizontally which is inside a window using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458415/how-to-scroll-scrollbar-horizontally-which-is-inside-a-window-using-java/35458538)

**Update 2:**

Please find attached image for little detailed dom.

[image]

**To notice:**

1. There are two horizontal scroll containers. Is that causing some trouble?
2. gridengine container is placeholder for 'wux-scroller' and it gets activated once user scrolls it manually

//Tried with below snippets but didn't work.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;    
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(-2000,0)");    
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[1];",driver.findElement(By.className("wux-layouts-gridengine-scroller-container")), 500);    
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[1];",driver.findElement(By.className("wux-scroller")), 500);
```

**Update 3: Solution**

Below implementation of python in selenium java helped to perform horizontal scroll in my application

```
 jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('wux-scroller wux-ui-is-rendered')[0].scrollLeft += 650");

jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('wux-scroller wux-ui-is-rendered')[0].scrollTo(350,0)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code using `Javascript` but with base on different attribute

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("wux-scroller"));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: \"auto\", block: \"center\", inline: \"nearest\"});", element);
```

**OR**

```
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[0].offsetWidth", element );
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but scroll left doesn't happen. No error is thrown.

Comment: Thanks but it's not scrolling left. For the same element scrollTop works fine and both scrolls are in same iframe.

Comment: I don't know why it is working... can you try this...just scroll left, it will not look for element...   executeScript(“window.scrollBy(-2000,0)”);

Comment: I have updated my findings under Update2. There seem to be two horizontal container.

Comment: I would say click anywhere under targeted scroller container then you can try above solution.

Comment: Thanks. I dont see a element defined for horizontal scroll. because grid-container highlights whole page including both scrolls under element 'wux-scroller'. If I take a screenshot of 'wux-scroller' it takes vertical scroll. So, its currently blocked. Alternatively,  I tried robot class and it works as expected but it comes with a dependency on xy-co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to test scroll or you need elements? For second case you can add `--headless` argument to driver. If it will be not enough add `window-size` argument with big resolution.

Comment: I want to test scroll

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a focus then only it will get scrolled.
E.g.

```
driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Trimmer")).click();
WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.id("brand"));
scroll.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```